# "Must declare the table variable" error within SQL Fiddle

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, sqlfiddle

I have an SQL Fiddle here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2ab05d/69

The code runs for me in SSMS SQL 2016, but it will not run within SQL Fiddle

Any way to fix it?

Thank you,

Lindsay

Comment: I think SQL Fiddle inserts separate batches between statements.  Regardless, just use a regular table instead.

Comment: Sql statement is valid. It is a limitation with SqlFiddle. I just test on my sql box without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug in http://sqlfiddle.com.

Your code runs fine on SQL Server 2016 in https://dbfiddle.uk though, so you could just switch to that one.

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e8d4c0af9df657e1e481c3d209600b56)**:

```
 id_num | religionCategory
------: | :---------------
2520985 | Catholic        
2541075 | Protestant      
2934559 | Buddhist        
3298125 | Protestant      
3378597 | Presbyterian    
3407535 | Catholic        
3448905 | Presbyterian    
2522034 | Protestant      
2543021 | All Other       
2933729 | Protestant      
3450792 | Jewish          
3041872 | Protestant      
3210738 | Catholic        
3220142 | Hindu           
3570871 | Protestant      
3348798 | Protestant      
2343987 | Protestant      
3433789 | Presbyterian
```